# bootstrap rails signin page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Right now my form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_tag session_path, method: 'post' do  %>

    <%= label_tag :email_or_username, "Email or Username:" %>

    <%= text_field_tag :email_or_username, nil, autofocus: true %>

    <%=label_tag :password, "Password:" %>

    <%= password_field_tag :password, nil  %>

    <%= submit_tag "Sign In", class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>

    No account yet? 
    <%= link_to 'Sign Up', signup_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
```

But I want it to look exactly like this:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

```
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

How do I incorporate the form_tag jazz into this bootstrap template?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff, I would suggest you read other stack overflow questions as there are several questions that answer this.. However this should point you in the right direction.

```
<div class="container">
  <center><h2>Please sign in</h2></center>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
          <%= f.label :email, "Email Address" %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
          <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
          <%= f.password_filed :password %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
          <%= f.submit "Log-in", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[Adding Twitter bootstrap styling to Rails form helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731170/adding-twitter-bootstrap-styling-to-rails-form-helpers)

This is a gem I use in my apps, it handles alot of the form creation and really all you have to do is add your customizations and styles, styling hints / tips /ideas come from bootstrap but check this out for form creation ect..

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form